# What does $d do in printf?

Tags: string, bash, printf, format-specifiers

I accidentaly wrote:

```
printf "here: %s $d\n" "${line:0:32}" "${#line}"
```

and got:

```
here: /home/gsamaras/Bash/libs/goodLib 
here: 103
```

Why?

Of course I meant to say `%d`, but I don't understand this behavior in the mistake I made. I would probably expect it to print "here: /home/gsamaras/Bash/libs/goodLib $d", like it would <kbd>[do in C](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zS6xVrpmNbEQUXP9)</kbd>... I couldn't find a duplicate or something on that, thus the question.

Comment: @Biffen I am fan of a string is double quotes and a character with single quotes paradigm followed in C and C++, but I see your point, thanks for the tip! RockyLi, I see, but still it's not clear why I get "here" twice...

Comment: @gsamaras Not to drag this out, but C and Bash are different languages, and single and double quotes have different meanings, respectively, in the two. I wouldn’t generally recommend migrating paradigms between languages like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First step, the shell performs variable expansion. Since there's no variable `$d`, it's replaced with an empty string. After variable replacement it's as if you'd written:

```
printf 'here: %s \n' /home/gsamaras/Bash/libs/goodLib 103
```

Now why does it print `here:` twice? When `printf` is given more arguments than format specifiers it repeats the format string, looping extra times until it's consumed all of its arguments. Since you have a single `%s` but two extra arguments it loops twice. It's as if you had written:

```
printf 'here: %s \n' /home/gsamaras/Bash/libs/goodLib
printf 'here: %s \n' 103
```

That is why you get two lines of output.

Answer (score 6):

Before the string `"here: %s $d\n"` is passed to `printf`, parameter expansions are performed by the shell. In this case `$d` is expanded to an empty string.

If you used single quotes around the string, or backslash-escaped the `$`, then you would see `$d` in the output.

Since you only have one format specifier in your string (`%s`) and passed two arguments after the format string, you end up with two lines of output:

> The format is reused as necessary to consume all of the arguments.

(from `man bash` in the `printf` section).